# What is propeller pitch speed?

Tags: propeller, airspeed, pitch

I was using Ecalc to calculate some flight parameters and then I came across this term called "propeller pitch speed". Can anyone explain me what this means?

Comment: "*Pitch Speed: the speed of the airflow leaving the propeller blade (nominal pitch speed based on the geometry). the theoretical maximum speed of your model neglecting aerodynamic drag of the model itself and propeller slip might be higher*". This is from the [user guide](https://www.ecalc.ch/calcinclude/help/propcalchelp.htm) of this tool.

Comment: Just to add to the comment above from @mins that prop pitch speed [cm/min] = linear pitch in cm x  RPMs,

Comment: @xxavier: It seems this is another (and confusing) name for [forward velocity](https://www3.nd.edu/~ame40462/garner_Model_Propellers_Article_2009.pdf).